# Is it possible to export a HMI in Automation Studio? (mapp view)

Tags: user-interface, br-automation-studio

I have created a simple HMI in mapp view in Automation Studio.

Is it possible to export the visualizations to another project? I don't need to export the current variables the HMI is using, since I want to attach new ones once the visual elements are exported into the new project.

Is this possible at all? Or do I need to start from scratch in the new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export selected elements from **File -> Export**. Both logical content and configuration content can be combined. After this you can import your exported content to your target project from **File -> Import**.

[Export dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7kLv.png)